# Библиотека графов где можно выводить тексты на столбцах.

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какая есть javascript библиотека отрисовки графиков, которая бы позволила в точности повторить такой макет?

1. То есть выводить буквы поверх столбцов, группировать столбцы.
2. Через css двигать любые элементы, сдигать через margin.
3. Была бы респонсибл(более менее нормально бы выводилась на маленьких экранах).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте библиотеку [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked)